# Loading a client certificate in asp-net core fails on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, x509certificate, windows-server-2012, client-certificates

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app that loads a client certificate to use when connecting to an external API. The code works perfectly when run locally using visual studio, but fails when run on our server.

I get the following error in the log:

> 2019-03-12 13:29:12.810 +01:00 [ERR] Connection id "0HLL6SPAO039S",
>   Request id "0HLL6SPAO039S:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown
>   by the application.
>   Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException:
>   Unknown error (0xc0000225)    at
>   Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(Byte[]
>   rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags
>   pfxCertStoreFlags)    at
>   Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[]
>   rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password,
>   X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String
>   fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   Geomatic.TinglysningApi.Startup.GetClientCertificate() in
>   C:\dev\TinglysningApi\Geomatic.TinglysningApi\Geomatic.TinglysningApi\Startup.cs:line
>   49    at Geomatic.TinglysningApi.Startup.b__4_0()
>   in
>   C:\dev\TinglysningApi\Geomatic.TinglysningApi\Geomatic.TinglysningApi\Startup.cs:line
>   35

The code that loads the certificate looks like this

```
    private X509Certificate GetClientCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);
    }
```

I have also tried with other X509KeyStorageFlags, and combinations of those but they all fail in the same way.

On the server I tried running my app as a IIS hosted app and I have tried running it from cmd using my own user and with cmd with admin permissions.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is identical between your local machine and the server?

Comment: yes, i copied it my self.

Comment: Is it possibly an ECDSA certificate whose curve was first added in Windows 10?

Comment: how would I check if that is the case?